Container resizing with CSS transition makes frame drops
I’m trying to apply an animation using CSS transitions.  The transition includes only a width change for the parent element of the Cesium container. 

<div class="page-container"> <!-- where the width transition happens -->
    <div class="map" id="map-container"></div>
</div>


Whenever I make the transition happen, it causes frame drops (in my case, dropped to between 38 and 50).  I am toggling the sidebar to show and hide, which changes the width of the Cesium container together, and I would like to ask how I can reduce the frame drops.
function toggleSidebar() {
    const sidebar = document.querySelector('.complain-sidemenu');
    const pageContainer = document.querySelector('.page-container-column');
  
    sidebar.classList.toggle('closed');
    pageContainer.classList.toggle('open');
}

here's my toggling code-block, and i tried using 'update' of CesiumJs at the end of this, it didnt work..
